# specifying a url function in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to specify a function url for a backbone model like this:

```
var Directory = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
  path: '/',
  entries: new DirectoryEntries
},

initialize: function() {
  this.listenTo(this, 'change:path', this.fetch);
  this.fetch();
},

parse: function(response, options) {
  if (response != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; ++i) {
      this.get('entries').add(new DirectoryEntry(response[i]));
    }
  }
  this.trigger('change');
},

url: function() {
  return '/svn-ls.php?path=' + this.get('path');
},
```

The initial call to fetch() in my initialize function seems to work fine, but when fetch gets called on a change to path, backbone tries to make the following JSON request: `http://localhost:8000/function%20()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20'/svn-ls.php?path='%20+%20this.get('path');%20%20%20%20}`

Ie, it seems to be trying to use this.url instead of actually calling it.

Anyone know what the problem is here?

**edit:** I changed the `listenTo` call to the following:

```
  var self = this;
  this.listenTo(this, 'change:path', function() { self.fetch(); });
```

and now everything seems to work. I have no idea why binding this.fetch directly messed things up, though.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do in your url function?

Comment: Backbone should always use `_.result(model, 'url')` which will check for a function vs scalar data and handle appropriately. My first guess is your code somewhere is actually accessing `.url` directly without the help of `_.result`. Are you using a recent version of backbone?

Comment: @frankblizzard I'm just returning a server url that should be called to get data from the server to populate the Directory object with the current path

Comment: @PeterLyons my definition of the url function is the only instance of 'url' in my code. here's the whole file: http://pastebin.com/vSfRit6n